# How to use PayPal in not allowed countries?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment

In some countries, **PayPal functionality** is trimmed (**you can't sell, you can't recieve money**), but I want to use it like for full. Can it be here some workaround? Can I use some VPN for this?

Comment: you mean, being able to withdraw money from your paypal account?

Comment: this is **one of** the things I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that, they'll will catch you. And where do you live? This can not be because you have to provide personal legal information. In some cases, you may be required to show even a passport or id. Why don't use local payment systems?

Comment: I want international possibilities, and my local is too young and bad

Answer (score 0):

You have to respect terms of service of face being disallowed from any service or merchant that you use. If you want to operate in multiple countries, you'll just need to find systems that work in each, and a way to implement that routes the order through the right merchant gateway.